# How to get the data returned in sip debugging on asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

Is it possible to store on a variable the sip header from asterisk?

> <--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.1.101:5060 ---> BYE
>   sip:101@192.168.1.102:5060 SIP/2.0 Via: SIP/2.0/UDP
>   192.168.1.101:5060;branch=z9hG4bK04B0006fcc7eb2a5c0e From: ;tag=gK0480049d To: "101"
>   ;tag=as0d6cf491 Call-ID:
>   22ea42397b241a6a26ba639c4f3fd2f1@192.168.1.102:5060 CSeq: 548735 BYE
>   Max-Forwards: 70 transferTarget: sip:102@192.168.1.102 Content-Length:
>   0

I wanted to get the value of "transferTarget" => sip:102@192.168.1.102.

Answer (score 0):

At current moment chan_sip support only headers from FIRST invite.

Accessible via function SIPHeader( read/write).

There are no realisation for other messages.

Chan_pjsip have HEP interface which allow save ALL traces to sql database(using kamailio), however it not very stable and require some special knowledge/experience for setup.

Comment: tnx, it is on BYE header, is this not accissible on "HANGUPCAUSE" ?

Comment: Read above. Nothing to add.

Comment: If you use chan_pjsip it is posible via sipcapture